# How I copy document form one user to another user google drive

Tags: php, google-drive-api

How I copy document form one user to another user google drive using google drive api with google service account.
if there is any php code snippet highly appreciate

Answer (score 0):

There is no account to account copy functionality in Google Drive API that I am aware of. You will have to download the file and then upload it to destination account.  If both accounts are in your control maybe you can use [`grive`](https://github.com/Grive/grive) to login the destination account on your machine and download file from source account into desired location via API. Let grive do the upload behind the scenes. This will offload the upload work of the php as well.

Comment: actually its can do I used this - https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/files/copy

Comment: it creates a copy of the file in the same account. Not between accounts